# How do i create a numbered report system?

Tags: discord.py

Hello so i am trying to create a report system where when a report is created it is report #0001 when a new one is it is report #0002 here is my code so far.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def report(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, reason=None):
        await ctx.send(f'{member} has been reported!')
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name='reports')
        embed = discord.Embed(name=f'Report incoming! #0001 ')
        embed.add_field(name='Member', value=f'{member}', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Member who reported them', value=f'{ctx.author}', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Reason', value=f'{reason}', inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name='Channel', value=f'{ctx.channel}', inline=False)
        await channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

Does anyone know how if so please respond to this thanks!

Comment: Will that reports deleted? Will your bot run 24 hours a day?

Comment: the reports will not be deleted and the bot will be ran 24 hours a day

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to store the report count somewhere, preferably a proper database. For this example you can use a json file, however, keep in mind that a json file as a database is fundamentally flawed due to its lack of atomic writes which can result in data corruption and loss.

```py
import json

@commands.command()
async def report(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    # Get currect report number
    with open('reports.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as counts:
        data = json.load(counts)
        counter = data['count']

    await ctx.send(f'{member} has been reported!')
    data = {"count": counter + 1}  # Add 1 everytime a report is invoked
    with open('reports.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name='reports')
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Report incoming! #{counter} ')
    embed.add_field(name='Member', value=f'{member}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Member who reported them', value=f'{ctx.author}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Reason', value=f'{reason}', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Channel', value=f'{ctx.channel}', inline=False)
    await channel.send(content=None, embed=embed)
```

reports.json

```
{
    "count": 0
}
```

Comment: Make sure your reports.json file looks like this before you use the command, https://mystb.in/DebutPartsBanners.json

Comment: trying ur answer again i get this error https://prnt.sc/uklokc

Comment: Looks like you're trying to send a message to a str, need to see the whole error

Comment: That is a error that is the paste bin link to the error i got given

Comment: The error you sent in this image https://prnt.sc/uklokc does not match the error in your pastebin. I believe you meant to send that to the other answer.

Comment: oh ok 2 secs let em get the other one

Comment: Did you update the code at all? The code above works for me and your traceback doesn't say which line is causing the issue.

Comment: The line that is causing the issue line 44 https://pastebin.com/iKWgCb18

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that there will be no internet problem or some other problems that will prevent the boat from running, you can simply do

```py
count = 0
@commands.command()
async def report(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, reason=None):
    count += 1
    #the rest of the command
```

Then you can change the embed name like this

`embed = discord.Embed(name=f'Report incoming! #{count}')`

But if you are not completely sure that the bot will have not any problem,
you can save the numbers in a file like **txt**, **json** or **yaml**. I'd prefer **txt** in that case because you just need to save one line of text. So you can do this:

```py
with open('counts.txt', 'r+') as file:
    number = file.read()
    if number == '':
        file.write('0')
@commands.command()
async def report(self, ctx, member : discord.Member, reason=None):
    with open('counts.txt', 'w+') as file:
        count = file.read()
        file.write(int(count)+1)
    embed = discord.Embed(name=f'Report incoming! #{count}')
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the response i get this error https://prnt.sc/uklhtn code is https://pastebin.com/L6bXP4Ps

Comment: Can you change the `with open('counts.txt', 'r+') as file:` with `with open('counts.txt', 'w+') as file:`? And also if it doesn't work, try to change the `if number == '':` with  `if not number:`

Comment: Hello i get the same error do i need to put something in the txt file

Comment: Probably yes. Delete the lines above the `@commands.command()` and put '0' inside the txt file.

Comment: Can you change the `with open('counts.txt', 'w+') as file:` `w+` with `r+`?